# Solving circle equations

Tags: java, geometry, quadratic, equation-solving

I'm looking for some assistance with solving the below equations in Java

```
(a-x1)^2 + (b-y1)^2 = r1^2 + r^2
(a-x2)^2 + (b-y2)^2 = r2^2 + r^2
(a-x3)^2 + (b-y3)^2 = r3^2 + r^2
```

Values of `x1`, `y1`, `r1`, `x2`, `y2`, `r2` & `x3`, `y3`, `r3` are known.
I need to solve for `a`, `b`, `r`

How to go about doing this in Java? I checked the [Commons Maths library](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/index.html) but didn't find how I could achieve this. It helps with linear equations though.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: Might want to ask [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) instead

Answer (score 3):

I think you need linear equations for Gaussian elimination.

If a, b, and r are what you need to solve for, it's obvious that these are non-linear equations.

You'll need a non-linear solver, like Newton-Raphson.

You'll have to linearize your equations.  Calculate the Jacobean for the differentials da, db, and dr.

You'll start with an initial guess

```
a = a(old)
b = b(old)
r = r(old)
```

use a linearized version of the equations to calculate an increment

```
2*(a(old)-x1)*da + 2*(b(old)-y1)*db = 2*r(old)*dr
2*(a(old)-x2)*da + 2*(b(old)-y2)*db = 2*r(old)*dr
2*(a(old)-x3)*da + 2*(b(old)-y3)*db = 2*r(old)*dr
```

update your guess

```
a(new) = a(old) + da
b(new) = b(old) + db
r(new) = r(old) + dr
```

and repeat until it converges (if it converges).

You should never solve linear equations using Gaussian elimination: it suffers from a number of problems.  A better idea is to do LU decomposition and forward-back substitution.

If my linearized equations are correct, they take the form `A(dx) = 0`.  What should the boundary condition be?

`(a, b)` are the coordinates for the center of the circle; `r` is the radius.

Do you really have three points `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)`, and `(x3, y3)`?  Or do you have lots more points?  If it's the latter, you'll need a least squares fit.

Comment: +1 Gaussian elimination definitely won't work.  This is more of a mathematics / numerical computation problem than a programming problem.  Most of the SO readership probably never did or have forgotten how to do the relevant maths.  (Myself included!)

Answer (score 0):

hope this method can give you some ideas:

```
public int[] getCoordinates(float XR_1, float YR_1, float XR_2, float YR_2,
                             float XR_3, float YR_3, int R1, int R2, int R3) {
    //define the positions
    int XU_1 = 0, YU_1 = 0, XU_2 = 0, YU_2 = 0, XU, YU;
    //define variables and arrays that needed
    float D0[][] = new float[17][50];
    float D1[][] = new float[17][50];
    float f[][] = new float[17][50];
    float fmin_1 = 0;
    float fmin_2 = 0;
    //define columns and rows
    int i, j;
    //Y goes from 0 to 49
    for(j=0; j<=49; j++){
        //X goes from 0 to 16
        for(i=0; i<=16; i++){
            D0[i][j] = (float) (Math.pow((i-XR_1),2) + Math.pow((j-YR_1),2) - Math.pow(R1,2));
            D1[i][j] = (float) (Math.pow((i-XR_2),2) + Math.pow((j-YR_2),2) - Math.pow(R2,2));
            f[i][j] = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(D0[i][j], 2) + Math.pow(D1[i][j], 2));
            //get two position where f[i][j] are the minimum
            //initialise the minimum two positions
            if(i==0 & j==0){
                fmin_1 = f[i][j];
                XU_1 = i;
                YU_1 = j;
            }
            else if(j==0 & i==1){
                if(f[i][j] < fmin_1){
                    fmin_2 = fmin_1;
                    fmin_1 = f[i][j];
                    XU_2 = XU_1;
                    XU_1 = i;
                    YU_2 = YU_1;
                    YU_1 = j;
                }
                else {
                    fmin_2 = f[i][j];
                    XU_2 = i;
                    YU_2 = j;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(f[i][j] < fmin_1){
                    fmin_2 = fmin_1;
                    fmin_1 = f[i][j];
                    XU_2 = XU_1;
                    XU_1 = i;
                    YU_2 = YU_1;
                    YU_1 = j;
                }
                else if(f[i][j] < fmin_2){
                    fmin_2 = f[i][j];
                    XU_2 = i;
                    YU_2 = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this method gives two closest points in the coordinate system, you can use the similar way to get the most ideal one.